# sqlite3 column does not exist

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to run queries on an `sqlite3` db/table i have made but i keep getting the error

> Error: near line 4: no such column: number_of_officers_employed
>
> Error: near line 6: no such column: year
>
> Error: near line 8: no such column: year
>
> Error: near line 10: no such column: year

My create-table code looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS lwenfemp(year INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, us_population INTEGER, number_of_officers_employed INTEGER, percent_change INTEGER, officers_per_100000_residents INTEGER);
```

Any idea why this might be? i am fairly new to `sqlite3` and apologise if i missed something that is obvious

My queries look like this:

```
SELECT year WHERE officers_per_100000_residents > '245';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add `FROM` table name:

```
SELECT year FROM lwenfemp WHERE officers_per_100000_residents > '245';
```

It will be fine, when using the backticks **``**

```
SELECT `year` FROM lwenfemp WHERE officers_per_100000_residents > '245';
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Worked perfectly.